# creating a golf tournament leaderboard

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a leader-board for a golf tournament that I'll participate in next month and I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it works.

I have a score entry page that is dumping into my SQL database, which works fine (all scores/names/totals are coming in),[[1](http://www.slamabamagolf.com/stack_question.html)] and I populate the scores as I want them to show on the leader-board, which works fine as well.
I am even `GROUP BY` (ing) them together so that there are no repeats[2].

The issue I am running into is that I cannot get the `GROUP BY` to add the total column together. I have tried several times to do `SUM(total)` in my query but it keeps knocking out the totals[3]. [here is what it looks like](http://www.slamabamagolf.com/stack_question.html) (each number above is the image) It is not showing any of the scores that were just populated.

Here is my current query:

```
$servername = 'mysql.thisplace.com'; 
$username = 'name'; 
$password = 'pword'; 
$dbname = 'dbase'; 

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed  " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT name, sum(total) FROM matchplay GROUP BY name ORDER BY -total DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "Name " . $row["name"] . " Score " . $row["total"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

There will be 4 rounds played between all of us, so here's my question:

How do I get 4 rounds from 16 different guys to add up together and show a leader? what would be the best query for that? and for the `SUM()` issue, am I doing something wrong in my query to make that happen?

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What does your table look like? Could you please add the relevant text from your link to this question to make it more complete? From how your questions is written, it's hard to tell exactly what the question and desired outcome is.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your use (rather the not-use of) an alias name to the column. You are confusing between the `total` as in the column name and the `total` as a sum total of individual scores. Hence, create a new `alias` to the sum total column as `Score` and order by the alias. This way, SQL will not confuse between the sum and the column name.

Modify your query to

`SELECT name, sum(total) as Score FROM matchplay GROUP BY name ORDER BY Score desc`;

The above query seems to do the trick and return the desired results ..!!

In addition to this, modify your while loop to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "Name " . $row["name"] . " Score " . $row["Score"]. "<br>";
}
```

Working SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ec2f/1)

Comment: i should have said that in my form i have all of the scores adding up from all of the holes: 

    <input type='text' name='hole1'> 
    <input type='text' name='hole2>....

and then in the php i have it dumping into the sql as 

    $totOut = ($hole1 + $hole2 ....
    $totIn = $(hole10 + $hole11 ....

    $total = ($totOut + $totIn) - $handi; 

it adds up the front 9 and the back 9 then minus the handicap for the total which is where i am getting the name for total. it is listed in the dbase as total

Comment: From my understanding, that should not cause any problem. Your alias in the SQL query seems to be wrong. Is the given above query working for you? Or is it showing any error?